How to solve the differential equation $x(\ln x-\ln y)dy - ydx = 0$ and find $y = f(x)$?
I am currently studying differential equations and encountered the following problem:
Given the equation:
$$
x(\ln x - \ln y) \, dy - y \, dx = 0
$$
I would like to solve it and find y as an explicit function of x（the general solution in the form y = f(x)）
I tried rearranging the equation and applying standard methods:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x \ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}
$$
However, I am unsure how to proceed further.
My book only provides the answer without the solution process:
$$
y = C\left(\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + 1\right)
$$
(where $C$ is a constant).
As a beginner in differential equations, I would greatly appreciate detailed solution steps or key insights into solving this. Thank you very much for your help!

Hint. Make the change of variable $y=tx$.

As a beginner?? If I go by traditional method then I have to use the method of exact differential equation to solve this...I guess there is some trick underlying here

What integrating factor did you get?

@EricTowers I got 1/y^2

@Gonçalo that will make the problem worse....try it yourself

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous, seeon solved the problem using my hint. ;-)

@Gonçalo I guess I need to go to the Himalayas for meditation

There is an explicit solution in terms of Lambert function.

Thanks to Gonçalo for the suggestion, it truly inspired me. I gave it another try, but I'm not sure if it's correct, and I still haven't arrived at the solution. I regret this. Actually, I only just learned the concept of differential equations today, and I feel I still need some help. Here are my thoughts:

It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

You are saying that you learnt the concepts of differential equation today. This question isn't your for you. Inform your teacher, that this problem is an advanced level question. It uses the concept of exact differential equations that is taught in the first year of college.

I indeed learned the concept of differential equations today. My previous exercise was dx+xydy=(y^2)dx+ydy, and I solved it. This is my second question.

I apologize for uploading the photo as I found it more convenient to write. I will make sure to be more careful next time. Thank you very much for the reminder.@
José Carlos Santos

You were almost there. Notice that $\ln(y/x)=\ln y - \ln x$, hence your last equation simplifies to $$\ln y - \ln(\ln(y/x)+1)=\ln C \implies y = C(\ln(y/x)+1).$$

@Gonçalo Yes, you are absolutely right. Thank you very much for your help.(●'◡'●)

Use the substitution $z=\frac{x}{y}$. From product rule we have
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{y-x\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}.$$
After rearranging it we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2\frac{dz}{dx}-y}{-x}.$$
Substitute this to the equation you get.
$$\frac{y^2\frac{dz}{dx}-y}{-x}=\frac{y}{x\ln\frac{x}{y}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\ln\frac{x}{y}}=-y\frac{dz}{dx}+1$$
$$\frac{1}{\ln z}=1-\frac{x}{z}\frac{dz}{dx}$$
$$\frac{x}{z}\frac{dz}{dx}=1-\frac{1}{\ln z}$$
$$\frac{x}{z}\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\ln z -1}{\ln z}$$
$$\frac{\ln z}{z(\ln z -1)}\,dz=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{\ln z}{z(\ln z -1)}\,dz=\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
Use the substitution $u=\ln z -1$. We have $du=\frac{1}{z}\,dz$, hence $dz=z\,du$. Then the integrals become
$$\int\frac{u+1}{zu}z\,du=\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
The right hand side is just $\ln x +C$.
The left hand side equals $\int\frac{u+1}{u}\,du=\int1+\frac{1}{u}\,du=u+\ln u$.
Hence we have
$$u+\ln u=\ln x +C$$
$$\ln z -1 + \ln (\ln z -1)=\ln x +C$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1+\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1\right)=\ln x +C$$
$$\ln x -\ln y -1 +\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1\right)=\ln x +C$$
$$\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1\right)=C'+\ln y$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1=e^{C'+\ln y}$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1=C''y$$
$$y=C'''\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-1\right)$$
$$y=C'''\left(\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{-1}-1\right)$$
$$y=C'''\left(-\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-1\right)$$
$$y=k\left(\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+1\right)$$

We have $$x(\ln x - \ln y) \, dy - y \, dx = 0
$$ In other words $$-x(\ln x - \ln y) \, dy + y \, dx =0
$$ Or in general form$$M(x,\,y)\;\mathrm{d}x+N(x,\,y)\;\mathrm{d}y=0$$
Now as $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\ne\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$
To make it exact, we have to multiply the whole equation by an integrating factor. Assume it is $\mu(x,y)$. Now assume that $\mu$ is just a function of $y$ 
$\mu =e^{\int h(y)dy}$ where $h(y)=\frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M}$
Solving gives $\mu=\frac{1}{y^2}$
Now use the general formula $$f(x,y)=\int A(x,y) dx+\int\left(B-\frac{\partial (\int A(x,y) dx)}{\partial y}\right)dy$$ where $f(x,y)$ is the solution of the exact differential equation $A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0$
In your case, $A=\mu M$ and $B=\mu N$
Put everything in the formula and solve for $f(x,y)$ and you will obtain $$\boxed{y = C\left(\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + 1\right)
}$$
